# Block declared variable visible outside?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

If I declare a variable within a block (see below) is there a way to specify that its visible outside the block if need be?

```
if(turbine_RPM > 0) {
    int intResult = [sensorNumber:1];
    NSNumber *result = [NSNumber numberWithInt:intResult];
}
return result;
```

or is the way just to declare outside the block scope?

```
NSNumber *result = nil;
if(turbine_RPM > 0) {
    int intResult = [sensorNumber:1];
    result = [NSNumber numberWithInt:intResult];
}
return result;
```

many thanks

gary

Comment: I don't think so, but in this case you could return from within the block without using variable.

Comment: Thank you, I was just curious if I was missing something. Its just quick sample code, but I assigned nil to result, just in case it misses the if.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare the variable outside of the block. Code blocks determine scope.

Answer (score 0):

I love one-liner:

```
return (turbine_RPM > 0) ? [NSNumber numberWithInt:[sensorNumber:1]] : nil;
```

As pointed out by Jasarien, you want to declare the variable outside the block. Or just return the `NSNumber` immediately.
The problem with your second example is that you will return an initialized variable if the if-statement fails, so you'd need to return something in an else-statement.